# Permanently Remove Google as the Default Search Engine in Firefox

Tags: firefox, google

I use MX Linux latest version (21) XFCE and Firefox 105.0.1.

Apparently I am the only person in the world offended that Google is built into Firefox. I searched using Start Page and it return no hits.  I don't see anyone else asking the same question on this forum.  Most people just want to use a different default which is easy to do. So easy and obvious in settings that I don't know why there are so many such questions!

I know how to CHANGE the default search engine. I know how to add search engines and even remove Google as the default using preferences in settings. I know how to prevent the address bar from conducting any searches using "key enable" in about:config.

I want to PERMANENTLY remove Google from Firefox so that it cannot be restored and I don't have to look at "search with Google..." in the address bar.  Yes, I hate Google and will go to any length to prevent my machine from sending anything to a Google IP address. Same with Microsoft but Microsoft was so much easier to purge. I do not want Firefox ever contacting a Google IP.

Using about:config I disabled anything that had a Google address or mentioned Google.  I disabled anything that required data from Google servers. But some of them re-spawned after being deleted or modified.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: search how to write a FF policy file. Some Linux distributions do what you are asking.

Comment: Thank you. I will do that.  I was unaware of FF policy files.